# Is there any shorter version for checking both empty and/or null string in Dart?

Tags: string, flutter, dart

I saw many similar questions but I haven't found one which satisfy the question I'm asking now.
So suppose I have 3 maps like these:

```
final map1 = {name: Bill, age: 34, nickname: ''};
final map2 = {name: John, age: 50};
final map3 = {name: Dan, age: 21, nickname: 'Avengers'};
```

I want to be able to check whether `nickname` is null or empty so I check like this:

```
if(map[nickname] != null && map[nickname] != '')
```

Or

```
if(map[nickname] == null || map[nickname] == '')
```

I had to use two conditional checks every time.

Is there a way in Dart so we can shorten this into one condition check?

Thanks and I apologize if this is a duplicate of some other question but I have searched a a bunch of similar questions without finding anything exactly for Dart yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write an extension for this

```
void main() {
  String str;
  print(str.isNotNullAndNotEmpty);
}

extension on String {
  bool get isNotNullAndNotEmpty => this != null && this.isNotEmpty;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```dart
if (['', null].contains(map[nickname]))
```

is the shorter version of

```dart
if(map[nickname] == null || map[nickname] == '')
```

This method uses the [`contains`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-core/Iterable/contains.html) method of the `List` class, which returns true if the collection contains an element equal to the input. So if your input `String` is either null or empty, it returns true.

Comment: Just because your shorter version looks short doesn't necessary means it is easier to understand, I suspect future readers would need to spend more time on shorter version than the longer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This also works. Thats why I also upvote it but it is hard to read. The `extension` method is a better solution for readability.

Comment: Thank you for the edit and the opinions, I will definitely try to explain it better next time!